# Chasing a vacancy where the end date for submissions keeps moving

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, recruitment, applications

I recently applied for a vacancy directly through a company's website. From postings on agency websites, it was obvious from the description that this vacancy was also being touted by several agencies

I sent my application in and the end date for submissions was due. The day before the end date, it was pushed back by 2 weeks. Today I have found out through the website it has been pushed back another 6 weeks

My question is - should I get in touch with the company to find out WHY it is being pushed back? Would that seem too eager/pushy? I appreciate there are many factors that could contribute to this (lack of applicants, relevant manager off, changes within the company of departments/roles) but I am keen to know if this is a non-starter now rather than in many weeks

If yes, should I just drop a short and direct email to the company?

Comment: Do you mean the date being push forward?

Comment: @Nazrein- I mean pushed back - so original date for example was 30th March, then it was 14th April and now it is 5th May

Comment: Likely because they haven't received enough interesting applications.  Someone finally told HR that finding left handed glass blowers who are also experts in exotic veterinary practice, specializing in penguins is going to take a while to fill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't ask. It is none of your business why they pushed back the date. You have no reason or standing to ask that question, it will come of as weird or demanding.

I would act like for any other candidacy : you applied (through the channels they asked, I hope), they know you're interested. If they are interested in you, they will contact you when the time is right for them. They might never contact you. So continue your job search as if they won't, and let it be a nice surprise if and when they do.

You could ask what their timeline is like if you yourself are on a tight schedule (aka you have a good reason to disrupt them), but I wouldn't even do that. They didn't contact you yet, they didn't show their interest in you. So again, being asked by a candidate they didn't reach out to what their timeline is, could be seen as weird and/or entitled. If you're lucky it won't make a bad impression, but it won't make a good one either way.

Just imagine that every candidate who applies sends a follow up e-mail. It's a nightmare for the recruiter, and it helps nobody.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should ask. Thing is, you need to know what question is to be asked.

Clearly, you have no business knowing why the dates are being pushed out. What you want to ask / know instead is, when are **you** going to get an interview scheduled?

Time is of essence, and if they keep on postponing the last date for closing out the application process, you may not be interested in the position anymore or have already found another job and accepted the offer. It's a valid scenario to ask for a tentative date for interview meeting in this scenario.

Comment: This presumes that OP is actually going to get an interview.  Not sure I would ask for my interview schedule if I don't know I'm getting one.

Comment: @cdkMoose Better knowing that I'm not getting one, vs. expecting something to appear with an unlimited timeline.

Comment: @SouravGhosh well, don't do that either

Answer (score 1):

There is only one reason for the dates to be pushed back: they haven't found the right candidate yet.

The only possible thing for you to do would be to contact a recruiter for that company, ensure that they did receive your application and inquire about when they would like to bring you in for an interview.  If they aren't interested in you it will become very apparent right then.

Contrary to what MlleMei said, I don't believe this makes a bad impression.  It actually makes a good one in that you are showing real interested.  That said, I wouldn't badger them and I certainly wouldn't bother with more phone calls after this one.